# Is it possible to connect to Postgres DB with PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: plsqldeveloper, postgresql-9.4

Is it possible to connect to Postgres DB with "**PL/SQL Developer**" like we can connect Oracle DB ?? Thanks.

Comment: I'm still missing using Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer with Oracle. But when moved to Postgres still couldn't find any client could match with  SQL Developer functionalities.

Answer (score -1):

No. You need to connect to a database with the network protocol for that database. Oracle PL/SQL Developer is written by Oracle, and therefore only supports Oracle databases.

Comment: No, PL/SQL Developer is not developed by Oracle, it is a product of Allround Automations. Oracle ships Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you pls suggest any similar tool for PostgreSQL? In "PL/Sql developer" I can explore to referenced tables very easily in single click. I am missing it in pgAdmin III

And I am currently accessing the DB that is in my local machine.

Comment: @Backbencher: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: Thanks. Mr. Unnamed horse

Comment: I think obsolete want a power tool like pl/sql developer on postgresql.

Comment: It is not written by Oracle.